# Football (Soccer) Player x,y,t data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, sports, time-series

I am looking for something that has the (x,y) coordinates of all players on the pitch over time.

I found this:
https://heim.ifi.uio.no/paalh/publications/files/mmsys2014-dataset.pdf
however, they only track the movements of the home team. I found various papers that discuss the techniques required to do this, but unfortunately don't provide the dataset.

Comment: does it have to be data from actual games? i'm wondering if you can hack into a playstation/wii/xbox fifa game and find there version. i'm entirely speculating, but that seems like something they would have a very firm hand on.

Comment: This could be interesting data to obtain in a range of sports.

Comment: check these references http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/lionel-messi-is-impossible/

Answer (score 4):

In the paper you link there is Reference 1 **http://home.ifi.uio.no/paalh/dataset/alfheim/**

which links to a nice page with full data exports for 3 games, including csv and videos (as you said, only home team).

```
'timestamp','tag_id','x_pos','y_pos','heading','direction','energy','speed','total_distance'
...
'2013-11-03 18:30:00.000612',31278,34.2361,49.366,2.2578,1.94857,3672.22,1.60798,3719.61
'2013-11-03 18:30:00.004524',31890,45.386,49.8209,0.980335,1.26641,5614.29,2.80983,4190.53
'2013-11-03 18:30:00.013407',0918,74.5904,71.048,-0.961152,0,2.37406,0,0.285215
'2013-11-03 18:30:00.015759',109,60.2843,57.3384,2.19912,1.22228,4584.61,8.14452,4565.93
'2013-11-03 18:30:00.023466',909,45.0113,54.7307,2.23514,2.27993,4170.35,1.76589,4070.
```