# Looking for soccer match raw data

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for soccer match data. Not summary data; I need in-game raw data that contains

1. who passed a ball to whom
2. all players' positions for every second

It does not matter which game it is. I need it for study and am ready to pay for it if needed.

Comment: The positional (x,y,t) data is here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7319/1511 Video too.

Comment: You could (obviously) watch a recording of a soccer game and note that down, perhaps even using AI techniques (based on uniform coloration and number?), unless that's what you're trying to develop in the first place